# How to create instance of Abstract Class of System controls in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I wrote this code in WPF:

```
   System.Windows.Controls.Panel Panel1 = null;
   Panel1 = new System.Windows.Controls.Panel();
```

But it is saying that:

```
Error1 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Windows.Controls.Panel'
```

How to solve this? Can anyone answer my query.

Comment: The error message is correct! You simply Cannot create an instance of any abstract class or interface. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @MitchWheat i want to create a Panel/

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh Maybe you want `StackPanel` or `Canvas`? They're both non abstract `Panel`s.

Comment: @MitchWheat-Joachim want DockPanel.

Comment: there are a lot of [Panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx#inheritanceContinued) that you can create

Comment: @MitchWheat  There is DockPanelA in my MainWindow.xaml. I defined MVVM framework to edit, delete and to update data in grid. I want to create new PanelB in my ViewModel Class, whenever a button named as "New" will be clicked. PanelA will get hide and PanelB should take position of Panle A?

Comment: @Zoya Sheikh - That's entirely separate question. Raise another question and post your relevant XAML code there. Not forgot to add what have you tried and what issue you facing while implementing it.

Answer (score 5):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) -

> Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, and are frequently either
>   partially implemented, or not at all implemented.

If you need `Panel`, create an object of classes deriving from [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx#inheritanceContinued). Most popular are

- Grid
- DockPanel
- StackPanel
- Canvas

Complete list for classes deriving from Panels can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx#inheritanceContinued).

This will serve your purpose -

```
System.Windows.Controls.Panel Panel1 = new System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel();
```

But I think you need to access `Dock` property of DockPanel (and properties specific to DockPanel), so you should create DockPanel object instead -

```
System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel Panel1 = new System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel();
```

Comment: you could give a reference to [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx#inheritanceContinued)

Comment: There is DockPanelA in my MainWindow.xaml. I defined MVVM framework to edit, delete and to update data in grid. I want to create new PanelB in my ViewModel Class, whenever a button named as "New" will be clicked. PanelA will get hide and PanelB should take position of Panle A?

Comment: Create a `ContentControl` and two `DataTemplates`. On button click change the `DataTemplates`. However, how that's related to creating an instance of an abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create instance of abstract class see [abstract keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You can derive from abstract class and then you can user your derived objces as the abstract type, see [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173152%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) and [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173149%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't think there is any need to derive a new class from `Panel` when there already are so many.